# Problems with setting up Java Runtime Enviroment

Tags: 22.04, java, jre

Fresh Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installation.
I installed JRE from Oracle website.
Added it to JAVA_HOME variable and PATH.
Application fails to launch,  with "No Java Runtime Environment(JRE) was found on this system"

Any ideas?

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7py9W.png)

Comment: You should post the full steps of what you already did.  Are you required to use Oracles Java 8?  You can install OpenJDK via apt.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code